# I can ssh into server A from server B. But I cannot ssh into server B from server A

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, port-forwarding, telnet

I have 2 servers in a data center. **Server B** is publicly accessible, as in, I can ssh into it.

**Server A** is not. So to access **Server A**, I ssh into **Server B**. And then from there, I ssh into **Server A**.

Now I was trying local port forwarding and it worked when I accessed the SSH port on **Server A**

(the inaccessible one) as in when I browsed **http://localhost:local_port**, 
I saw the whole SSH

unrecognized protocol stuff on the webpage.e.g.

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Protocol mismatch.
```

Then I tried to access the tomcat port via local port forwarding, and I couldn't, even though the connection to the in-between server was established successfully.

The browser just kept trying to connect but nothing happened.

Troubleshooting showed me that I could both telnet and ssh into the offending **Server A** from **Server B**. But I could neither telnet nor ssh into **Server B** from Server A. Even after unblocking the concerned ports with

```
 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport --syn -j ACCEPT
```

Summary? the offending server is accessible on the ssh port which is useless to me for my purposes.

**How do I make this server(**Server A**) accessible on other ports? like my tomcat port for instance.  Thanks**

**EDIT**

When I try to ssh from Server A to Server B, I get

```
ssh: connect to host ip_value port port_no: Connection refused
```

When I run this:

```
service ssh status
```

I get:

```
ssh: unrecognized service
```

When I do:

```
ssh -v root@ip -p port_no
```

I get:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 111.1111.xx.x [111.1111.xx.x] port 1000.
debug1: connect to address 111.1111.xx.x port 1000: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 111.1111.xx.x port 1000: Connection refused
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can Telnet into a Linux CentOS system but cannot SSH into it. My colleagues say they can SSH into it](http://superuser.com/questions/1065639/i-can-telnet-into-a-linux-centos-system-but-cannot-ssh-into-it-my-colleagues-sa)

Comment: No it isn't. That issue you linked was mine..and its fixed now

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I cannot ssh from the protected server back into the publicly accessible one. But I can ssh in the reverse direction. How can I enable ssh from the protected one to the publicly accessible one

Comment: Ugh... this sounds complicated.  Especially those IPv4 addresses with four digits in the second octet.  So let's try some simple things.  On server A, can you connect to the address 127.0.0.1 ?  Does the SSH log (possibly /var/log/*auth*log*) show any details?  Can you see the incoming traffic using tcpdump?

Comment: @TOOGAM, I just put the dummy ip there, it has nothing to do with the actual format.the actual format is aaa.bb.ccc.dd

Comment: I cant telnet localhost(127.0.0.1). The server is centos and I cant find authlog...but there is a /usr/share/selinux/devel/include/system/authlogin.if and I cant ssh it too, @TOOGAM

Comment: On Server A, use " netstat -na | grep 22 " to confirm that you have an SSH server listening on port 22.  Try running: sudo $( which sshd ) ; echo ${?}

Comment: I have tcp connections established on the ssh port on the sey ip address. And it is also listening on the set port

Answer (score 0):

Some [basic features](https://blog.0xbadc0de.be/archives/300) of OpenSSH with a few advises, prioritized in reliability followed by urgent graphical annotations.